# me da error en el constructor de la clase c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
namespace textTDengine{
typedef const char* spr;
enum direction{up,down,left,right};
struct vector2{
    float x;
    float y;


    vector2(float x,float y){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        }

        COORD vector_to_coord(){
            COORD result;
            result.X = x;
            result.Y = y;
            return result;
        }


};


class object{
    spr sprite;

    vector2 position;

    direction dir;
    public:
    void draw_on_screen(){
        HANDLE hcon;
        hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,position.vector_to_coord());

        printf(sprite);
    }
    //aqui en el constructor me da error
    object(spr a_sprite,vector2 pos){
        sprite = a_sprite;
        position = pos;

    }

    void SetPos(vector2 pos){
        position = pos;
    }

    void SetDir(direction d_dir){
        dir = d_dir;
    }

    void SetSpr(spr a_sprite){
        sprite = a_sprite;

    }



};      

}
```

Comment: podrias mencionar concretamente que error te da?

Comment: Veo dos definiciones de clase con sendos constructores cada una. ¿Cuál es el que da error?

Answer (score 1):

En C++ el compilador es capaz de crear una serie de constructores... siempre y cuando se den ciertas circunstancias. Por ejemplo, para que el compilador cree el constructor por defecto es necesario que:

- No se haya implementado ningún constructor propio
- No se haya implementado el constructor por defecto de forma explícita

La primera regla no se cumple en el caso de `vector2`:

```
struct vector2{
    vector2(float x,float y){ // <<--- Constructor propio
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        }
};
```

Como tu no has declarado el constructor por defecto y el compilador no va a crear dicho constructor entonces se produce un error aquí:

```
class object{

    vector2 position; // (1)

    object(spr a_sprite,vector2 pos){ // (2)
        sprite = a_sprite;
        position = pos; // (3)
    }
```

Los comentarios se refieren a lo siguiente:

1. La clase `object` tiene una variable miembro de tipo `vector2`
2. En virtud del punto anterior, en el constructor de `object` se debe llamar a algun constructor de `vector2`, como no se ha invocado ningun constructor de forma explícita el compilador intenta llamar al constructor por defecto. Como dicho constructor no se encuentra se provoca el error.
3. Esto no es más que una asignación posterior a la construcción.

La solución pasa por invocar a los constructores en vez de realizar asignaciones:

```
object(spr a_sprite,vector2 pos)
  : sprite(a_sprite), position(pos) // Llamadas a constructores
{
}
```